# How to perform more than one operation in django function view

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to perform 2 operation with in a single function view. But it perform only first operation. Which operation i mentioned first only that operation is executed second operation is not executed. Any other way to solve this problem.

```
def home_view(request):
    if 'username' in request.session:
        if 'username' in request.session:
            username = request.session['username']
            business_objs = AddBusiness.objects.all().values()
            return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'business_objs': business_objs})
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            username = request.session['username']
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                profile_info = Profile.objects.filter(username=username).values()
                for i in profile_info:
                    profiledict = i
                    return render(request, 'home/index.html',
                                  {'profile_first_name': profiledict['first_name'],
                                   'profile_last_name': profiledict["last_name"],
                                   'profile_phone_number': profiledict['phone_number'],
                                   'profile_email': profiledict['email'], 'profile_address': profiledict['address'],
                                   'profile_image': profiledict['image']})
                return redirect('/home/')
            return redirect('/home/')

    else:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

Comment: It's not executed because you return response after first condition, so it doesn't check the next condition at all. If you want some more logic to be performed you need to do it before you return a response.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try like this:

```
def home_view(request):
    if 'username' in request.session:
        if 'request.method == 'GET':
            username = request.session['username']
            business_objs = AddBusiness.objects.all().values()
            return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'business_objs': business_objs})
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.session['username']
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                profile_info = Profile.objects.filter(username=username).values()
                for i in profile_info:
                    profiledict = i
                    return render(request, 'home/index.html',
                                  {'profile_first_name': profiledict['first_name'],
                                   'profile_last_name': profiledict["last_name"],
                                   'profile_phone_number': profiledict['phone_number'],
                                   'profile_email': profiledict['email'], 'profile_address': profiledict['address'],
                                   'profile_image': profiledict['image']})
                return redirect('/home/')
            return redirect('/home/')

    else:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

In that way, you will be able to handle both `GET` and `POST` request using this function based view. More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method).

Comment: it's performing only first operation.

Comment: You need to make POST request to that url. I think you can look into this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/